# How to install the license when the library is being used in multiple projects

Tags: postsharp

I've a main dll where i'm using postsharp, but many others references it. Where must be placed the postsharp.config file?

I do not want to install visual studio postsharp tools in every machine I edit my solution.

Answer (score 0):

As stated at http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-system:

> PostSharp will automatically load a few well-known configuration files if they are present on the file system, in the following order:
>
> 1. Any file named postsharp.config located in the directory containing the MSBuild project file (csproj or vbproj, typically), or in any parent directory, up to the root. These files are loaded in ascending order, i.e. up from the root directory to the project directory.
> 2. Any file named MySolution.pssln located in the same directory as the solution file MySolution.sln .
> 3. Any file named MyProject.psproj located in the same directory as the project file MyProject.csproj or MyProject.vbproj .
>
> For instance, the files may be loaded in the following order:
>
> 1. c:\src\BlueGray\postsharp.config
> 2. c:\src\BlueGray\FrontEnd\postsharp.config
> 3. c:\src\BlueGray\FrontEnd\BlueGray.FrontEnd.Web\postsharp.config
> 4. c:\src\BlueGray\Solutions\BlueGray.pssln assuming that the current solution file is c:\src\BlueGray\Solutions\BlueGray.sln.
> 5. c:\src\BlueGray\FrontEnd\BlueGray.FrontEnd.Web\BlueGray.FrontEnd.Web.psproj assuming that the current project file is c:\src\BlueGray\Solutions\BlueGray.sln.